# Kotlin with Eclipse and JRebel

Tags: eclipse, kotlin, jrebel

I have a JEE project that is purely Java and I have turned it into a Java and Kotlin mixed codebase. I have been using JRebel and when I save a change to a Java class, it is automatically compiled, placed in the project `/bin` directory as a `.class` file, and the change is automatically picked up by JRebel and deployed to my running web application.

Now when I save a change to a Kotlin class, it does not get automatically compiled, thus there is no new `.class` file in the `/bin` directory and JRebel, therefore does absolutely nothing.

This problem is mentioned in the comments of the JetBrains Kotlin Blog (https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2015/06/kotlin-eclipse-plugin-0-2-0-2/) and has a ticket in the JetBrains Kotlin tracker (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-8123 - it has be languishing there for about a year). The Eclipse Kotlin plugin is failing to compile the class file on save for incremental builds. See this related posting:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/36259756/2346823

I've found I can trick the Kotlin plugin to create the class file by running a program that uses them - but this is super stinky...

Has anyone figured out how to make the Eclipse Kotlin plugin automatically compile and build the `.class` file when the source file is saved? Any other hints or tricks would be welcome (other than, "Switch to IntelliJ IDEA")

Thank you.

Comment: log a support ticket with the Jrebel guys, they're pretty good

Comment: Not really related to JRebel as it's a fault in the kotlin plugin. I guess you can compile the classes externally in the meantime, e.g. `mvn compile` (make sure build tool and eclipse compile to same /bin or /target/classes path)

Comment: Right now I have written a Perl script that monitors all Kotlin files for changes, and does a `gradle compileKotlin` when something changes, then looks for updated `.class` files in the `./build/kotlin-classes` directory and copies them into the Eclipse `./bin` directory.  It works, but is a stop-gap kludge which I am not proud of....